# How to handle added options with multilineSelectmenu (jQuery UI Widget)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I want to use a jquery widget extension of multilineSelectmenu (https://github.com/ainterpreting/jquery-multilineSelectmenu). 
However, 
After opening the select box even once, new options (added by clicking the button "add item") are not been appeared in the box.
   [Here is an example.](https://codepen.io/NomuraS/pen/aqOrzL) And the following is the content of multilineSelectmenu

```
/* this is the custom selectmenu widget extension add multiline and css theming support */
var multilineSelectmenu = $.widget("ui.multilineSelectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _setText: function (element, value) {
        if (value) {
            if (value.indexOf('|') !== -1) {
                var lines = value.split('|');
                value = '<span class="ui-selectmenu-menu-item-header">' + lines[0].trim() + '</span>';
                for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    value = value + '<span class="ui-selectmenu-menu-item-content">' + lines[i].trim() + '</span>';
                }
            }
            element.html(value);
        } else {
            element.html("&#160;");
        }
    }
});
```

I search this problem several hours, but because I don't know much about jquery-ui and its widget, I could not settle by myself. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to destroy and recreate widget after adding new option/options:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
        $('#select').append($('<option>').html('new| option'));
        $("#select").multilineSelectmenu('destroy');
        $("#select").multilineSelectmenu();  
 })
```

[See here for example](https://codepen.io/112g/pen/BYoogY?editors=1111)